# how to remove new line after form tag for a dropzone

Tags: php, html, css

here is my html and css code:

```
<div class="divphotos">
     <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone" id="mydropzone" ></form>
     <div id="divphotos-content" >
           <?php
                require 'getimages.php'; 
            ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
#mydropzone {
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    border: 2px dashed black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I have tried `inline` and `inline-block` but the drop zone always makes a  new line like this :
[image]

**edit**

here is getimages.php:

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
require 'dbConfig.php';

// Get files from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY id DESC");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $filePath = 'images/jill_photos/'.$row["file_name"];
        $fileMime = mime_content_type($filePath);
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $filePath; ?>" width="130px" height="130px" />
    <?php 

}
}else{ 
        ?>
                <p>No file(s) found...</p>
        <?php
} 
?>
```

thank you for your help.

Comment: those are 2 completely different questions, I'd suggest that you ask one css and one php questions, also you should supply the html you are using to display the mages (like in your example-picture)

Comment: done. removed the second question